# Using Checkbox to join indexes for search in c# for mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have made a simple database search program using c# linq and mysql(code below) which works pretty well. This database has 16 columns 6 of which are for address (State,City,District,Street, Building Name, Door Number). My code now searches for many variations of indexes aside from anything related to address and as seen below ID is overriding value. What my prof. wants is to search with ID and address values to find who might be from the same place. The way this is wanted is to have a checkbox.

If checkbox is clicked and ID entered the search result returned with everyone with the same address and if nobody else has the same address then just the entered ID value to return.The rest of the index values doesn't needed for this operation. My problem with this whole equation is I can't find any applicable way to join the 6 address columns and do a double search with ID and the whole adress. I have to use linq as it is required.

Code Sample;

```
var query = from i in sqlcmd.table select i;

        if (ID.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            double id = Convert.ToDouble(ID.Text);
            query = query.Where(s => s.ID == id);
        }

        else
        {
            if (Name.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.Name == Name.Text);

            }
            if (Sname.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.Sname == Sname.Text);
            }

            if (ClassList.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(s => s.ClassList == ClassList.Text);
            }
        }

        gridview.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

P.S: Thx to @juancarlosoropeza for heads-up of the mess of a question I made.

Comment: What is the problem with current code? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: thank you I actually did made a mess of the question.Edited and hopefully it is clarified.

Comment: I still fail to understand if there is a question there :(. We usually ask for db schema, sample data and expected result so we get the idea of what are you trying to acomplish. I dont see any of that.

Answer (score 0):

just include the check value on the `if` conditions.

```
if (chkName.Checked && Name.Text.Length > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Name == Name.Text);
}

if (chkSName.Checked && Sname.Text.Length > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Sname == Sname.Text);
}

if (chkClassList.Checked && ClassList.Text.Length > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.ClassList == ClassList.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understood what you are looking for but I'll give it a try.
If I got you right you are looking for a way to find anybody who has the same address as the person with a given ID. If you want to exclude the person with the given ID just uncomment the last line in the where-clause of the query.

```
        var query = from i in sqlcmd.Table select i;

        if (ID.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            var personGivenByID = from person in query.AsEnumerable()
                                  where person.ID == Convert.ToDouble(ID.Text)
                                  select person;

            var sameAddressLikeGivenPerson = from row in query.AsEnumerable()
                                             where row.State == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().State
                                             && row.City == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().City
                                             && row.District == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().District
                                             && row.Street == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().Street
                                             && row.BuildingName == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().BuildingName
                                             && row.DoorNumber == personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().DoorNumber
                                           //&& row.ID != personGivenByID.FirstOrDefault().ID
                                             select row;

            gridview.DataSource = sameAddressLikeGivenPerson != null ? sameAddressLikeGivenPerson : sameAddressLikeGivenPerson;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I had exams so could not check back but this is exactly what I'm looking for however this has to be optional hence the checkbox. I need the above code and this code . So How do I made this part of the code work when the user checks the checkbox but can search with the others if it is not. Thank You.

Comment: If the rest of your code works fine just copy and paste it. Maybe you have to add another if-condition like "if (chkBox.Checked && ID.Text.Length > 0) { my query } else if (!chkBox.Checked) { rest of your code }".